# Boolean function minimization

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Does there exist a Boolean function for which no sum-of-products expression that minimizes the number of products also simultaneously minimizes the number of literals (counting repetitions)? Minimization methods like K-maps choose one of these objectives and optimize; I am just wondering if minimizing one automatically minimizes the other, or there is a counter-example.

Some clarificatory comments:

1. Sum-of-products refers to OR of ANDs. Each AND involves an arbitrary number of literals. Each literal is a variable of its complement. While counting the number of products of such an expression, each product contributes 1 irrespective of the number of literals it involves.
2. The function could be partial (i.e. "don't care" on some inputs)

Comment: By "sum-of-product" I refer to Or of ANDs. Each AND may involve several literals. Each literal can be a variable or its complement.

Comment: Also, the function may be partial (i.e., "don't care"s on some inputs).

Comment: I can prove that if there is any counterexample (a function and a pair of solutions to it $A$ and $B$, with $A$ having the fewest possible terms and the fewest possible literals among all such solutions, and $B$ having the fewest literals overall, such that $B$ has strictly fewer literals than $A$ and strictly more terms), then there's a counterexample (possibly w.r.t. a different function) in which every subset $X$ of $k$ terms in $A$ requires at least $k+1$ terms in $B$ to cover the same required-to-be-true minterms that $X$ covers. This seems a strong constraint, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question to specify more precisely how you count the number of products.  If you have an OR of AND-clauses containing 1, 2, 3 variables respectively, it's not clear if you would count that as 0+1+1 products (a product of 3 terms counts as a single product, i.e., unlimited fan-in AND gates) or as 0+1+2 products (fan-in 2), or something else.

Comment: Have you tried writing a program to do an exhaustive search, for randomly chosen Boolean functions on a very small number of variables?  That might be a useful way to get some increased confidence in your conjecture, or to find a counterexample.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I can also prove that. You may also show that each term of A has strictly more literals than each term of B. These seem to be the first things that get proved when one starts thinking about this question :-)

Comment: @D.W. Each product is  an AND of any number of literals. I have not yet written any program; I thought it may be a god idea to first check if this is already known.

Comment: @Swagato, I know that, but I'm asking how you count the number of products.  If I have the AND of N literals, is that N-1 products or 1 product?

Comment: @D.W. 1 product.

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] the question to state that in the question (as I had suggested previously...)